# Google play incompatible with many devices

Tags: android

I just upload my app and I found that in almost 60% of the devices isn't compatible (Google Play, compatibly devices).

I have this on my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I try it on Nexus 7 (2012) and LG Optimus and none are compatible any ideas?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` then only devices with rear facing cameras will be included.

The Nexus 7 (2012) will not be compatible as it only has a front facing camera.

Android 4.2 added `android.hardware.camera.any`, which will allow devices that have a front or back facing camera.

See here for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features

Also, if having a camera isn't mandatory for your app you can specify `android:required="false"` for the uses-feature. If you don't specify this  then the default is android:required="true" and any device which does not have the feature will be deemed incompatible.